# Ignore the colour white in the imagemagick convert colors histogram output

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to ignore/filter white and those that are close to white when using this type of command

`convert $file -colors 10 -format "%c" histogram:info:`

I have some images that are predominantly white in their content and i'd like to focus on the other colours.

I thought i could use something like `-fuzz 20% -fill "#0000ff" -opaque white` to change all white and white'ish into a simple blue which i could then grep out in the histogram output but no luck.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction or offer an example please ?

Let's say for example i have a photo that contains a very overexposed sky i.e lot's of white. I'd like the histogram output to ignore that part of the photo and instead output the other top 10 colours that are in the photo.

Thanks

fLo

Comment: What do you mean *"no luck"* ? What command did you use? What result did you get? What was wrong with it, or what were you expecting? Do you have a sample image please?

Comment: Why wouldn't `| grep -v white` work?